# How to remove a programmatically created subview from Superview when button touch up inside?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, subview

[image]

I have a system that generate new view (marked with blue rect on the picture) and button (marked with green circle ) as a subview of Superview(marked with red rect) when user tapped to another button(named as Button). They all created programmatically. I can remove the "minus button" according it's button.tag with Action Messages. The problem is that how do I remove that subview next to minus button? It has also same tag with minus button.

My mainButton IBAction below ;

```
 @IBAction func mainButton(sender: UIButton) {
        drawThem()


        minusButtonY = counter == 0 ? (minusButtonY + 101) :(minusButtonY + 68)
        borderY = counter == 0 ? (borderY + 86) : (borderY + 68)
        counter++
        drawFooter()
        completePaymentView.contentSize = counter > 7 ? (CGSizeMake(500.0, ( borderY ))) : (CGSizeMake(500.0, ( 490.0 )))

    }
```

And  the the method where I generate new view and button ;

```
func drawThem() {
      //creating minus button
            let image = UIImage(named: "minus.png") as UIImage?
            let button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
            var mX : CGFloat = 2.0
            var mY : CGFloat = minusButtonY >= 36.0 ? minusButtonY : 36.0

            button.frame = CGRectMake(mX, mY, 22, 22)
            button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
            button.tag = Int(counter)
            button.addTarget(self, action:"btnTouched:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
            completePaymentView.addSubview(button)

            //drawing payment section border
            var x : CGFloat = 43.0
            var y : CGFloat = borderY >= 20.0 ? borderY : 20.0

            let size = CGSize(width: 485 , height: 55)

            let borderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x , y: y), size: size))
            borderView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.83, green: 0.85, blue: 0.88, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
            borderView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
            borderView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
            borderView.tag = counter
            completePaymentView.addSubview(borderView)

            //drawing UIImage and Labels into border
            let imageName = "circle.png"
            let thumb = UIImage(named: imageName)
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: thumb!)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 14, y: 8, width: 55, height: 35)
            borderView.addSubview(imageView)


            let label1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 85, y: 20, width: 100, height: 18)) as UILabel
           label1.text = "Some Text"
           label1.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.49, green: 0.54, blue: 0.6, alpha: 1.0)
           label1.font = label1.font.fontWithSize(14.0)
           label1.textAlignment = .Left
            borderView .addSubview(label1)

            let label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 370, y: 20, width: 100, height: 18)) as UILabel
            label2.text = "Some Text"
            label2.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.49, green: 0.54, blue: 0.6, alpha: 1.0)
            label2.font = label2.font.fontWithSize(14.0)
            label2.textAlignment = .Right
            borderView .addSubview(label2)


        }
```

and Target Action below ;

```
func btnTouched(button : UIButton){

    button.removeFromSuperview()


}
```

Comment: Find it by `tag` - there are a lot of examples in the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following in btnTouched method. Actually I am searching through all the subviews to find the tag.

```
for view in self.view.subviews as! [UIView] {
    if view.tag == button.tag {
    view.removeFromSuperview()

  }
}
```

Comment: That's work ! I just changed self.view.subviews with self.completePaymentView.subviews according to my code and gotcha! Thanks.